# Serialize the Inner property of the class to Json object in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have following set of classes.

```
    public class ClassOne
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property1", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property2", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }

        public ClassTwo ClassTwo { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassTwo
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property3", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "property4", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    }
```

I need a help from you guys to serialize the `ClassOne` object into `json` object.Required Output is :I used `Newtonsoft.Json` for the serialization.

```
{
    "property1":"test",
    "property2":"test",
    "property3":"test",
    "property4":"test",
}
```

Comment: why do you not use inheritance public `class ClassOne : ClassTwo {...}`

Comment: @ShaunWilde - doesn't make any sense to assume you can do that.

Comment: @ShaunWilde : Nope I'm unable to do the inheritance here.

Comment: @Thilina H. That should just work.  I copied & pasted your code, created a couple of objects, called `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, and as expected, got the JSON `{"property1":"xyz","property2":"abc","ClassTwo":{"property3":"zzz","property4":"123"}}`.  Some more code could help in tracking down the problem.

Comment: Just re-read your question - I think it got confusing after the update. I think I understand now.  You want to flatten your output to what you are showing in the answer, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Every one ! I have sorted my problem using custom converter as follows.

```
    public class FlattenJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        #region Public Methods

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var jToken = JToken.FromObject(value);
            if (jToken.Type != JTokenType.Object)
            {
                jToken.WriteTo(writer);
                return;
            }

            var jObject = (JObject)jToken;
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            WriteJson(writer, jObject);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        private void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, JObject value)
        {
            foreach (var property in value.Properties())
            {
                var jObject = property.Value as JObject;
                if (jObject != null)
                    WriteJson(writer, jObject);
                else
                    property.WriteTo(writer);
            }
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
           object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Usage :

```
    // To Flatten the Json result
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new FlattenJsonConverter() },
    };

    var serializedJsonObject = JObject.Parse(testclassObject, settings));
```